# Disable Display Standby when in Developer Mode missing in Android 2.3

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s, 2.3-gingerbread, screen

I'm a little bit confused about the missing Option to deactivate the Display Standby in Developer Mode.

In 2.2 there was a switch in Application --> Development. But in 2.3.3 this switch is vanished and it is really annoying if the Phone gets black every 10 minutes.

So my Question, how can I override the Display Timeout in Developer Mode, is the switch at another Place or is it outpatched?

Phone is a Samsung Galaxy I9000.

Thanks.

Comment: Ok, i'm trough every Menu on the Phone and i definitltly don't find the Option :(

Comment: It seems, that this is a special Problem with the Galaxy S, because on my other Nexus S with Version 2.3.4 there is the Option available.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this app: [StayAwake](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.gmail.developer.runks.enji), worked for my stock I9000 (now running a custom rom, still works most of the time but a bit buggy).

Comment: Thanks, this solve the Problem. Why has Google outpatched this feature??

Comment: @Chris: It was probably Samsung that removed it. The only phones I've heard of that lack the "Stay Awake" option are Samsung phones, but every non-Samsung phone I've seen has it. I've read theories ([example](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1091018)) that it was to prevent burn-in on the SAMOLED screen, but I don't know if that's true or not.

Comment: @eldarerathis: Burn-in Issues in SAmoled? I never heard about this, but it makes sense then. Thanks for this Info.

Comment: Yep, I have a minor burn-in of the notification bar but it can only be seen in test mode with the blue screen (or similar). Not visible normally, even though I've kept the screen on about 60hrs/week

Comment: @onik That [StayAwake](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.gmail.developer.runks.enji) app is so buggy that it ruined my screen backlight/locking completely, even after I uninstalled it! I think it should be renamed StayAway... :/

Comment: Actually it does not solve the problem, because it does not make a difference for AC connection and USB one. So it will keep screen on also on regular charging.

Answer (score 1):

If StayAwake is too buggy, try Tasker. I created a task which activates when usb is plugged in to keep the screen awake.

Seriously, with a rooted phone the following create a nirvana environment:

```
Titanium Backup
DroidWall
LBE Privacy
Tasker
```

You get pretty much total control over everything except the stupid 100% battery beep (you need a special ROM for that).

Answer (score 0):

Although it doesn't answer the actual question, but may be helpful for few of the users who are looking for the answer.

**For android 4.2 and above**, I created an app for this purpose ([Keep Awake for Debugging](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.arpitgupta.keepawakefordebugging)). It will keep your phone unlocked and screen awake **only** when you have USB/wireless debugging enabled.

Comment: The Android version in question is 2.3 but your app doesn't appear to support it. Any reason for not mentioning that important point?

Comment: Apologies, updated now.