# "keep screen on if USB debugging" application?

Tags: lock-screens, usb-debugging

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Disable Display Standby when in Developer Mode missing in Android 2.3](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/12912/disable-display-standby-when-in-developer-mode-missing-in-android-2-3)

CyanogenMod has this "keep screen on if USB debugging" as a feature in `Settings > Applications > Development`, but my phone isn't supported by CyanogenMod and so this little life saver is missing.

I searched the Market and all I could find is [Screen On](https://market.android.com/details?id=gr.androiddev.ScreenOn&feature=search_result) which only attaches to an application, not USB debugging.

Is there a simple, tiny app that does only "keep screen on if USB debugging"?

Comment: @eldarerathis Thanks! My phone runs 2.2, not 2.3 but I'll give it a try.

Comment: I think it's more of a Samsung thing in general. Is your phone a Samsung device?

Comment: @eldarerathis Yes it is. :) And I think that the little app you pointed to works for me very well. If you post your comment as an answer, I will accept it. +2.

Comment: @eldarerathi That [StayAwake](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.gmail.developer.runks.enji) app is so buggy that it ruined my screen backlight/locking completely, even after I uninstalled it! I think it should be renamed StayAway... :/

Comment: @eldarerathis I forgot to describe the symptoms: Every time I start an application (*any* application), the screen goes blank and the phone is locked. I have to press the power button to turn the screen on and sweep my finger to unlock the phone. How do I solve this now?